# How to apply group by Keys to the relevant Groups

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe where i use group by to group them like follows

```
Name      Nationality    age
Peter     UK             28
John      US             29 
Wiley     UK             28 
Aster     US             29 

grouped = self_ex_df.groupby([Nationality, age])
```

1. Now i want to attach a unique ID against each of these values

I am trying this though not sure it works?

```
uniqueID = 'ID_'+ grouped.groups.keys().astype(str)

    uniqueID    Name      Nationality    age
     ID_UK28    Peter       UK             28
     ID_US29    John        US             29 
     ID_UK28    Wiley       UK             28 
     ID_US29    Aster       US             29
```

2. I want to now combine this into a new DF to something like this

   ```
    uniqueID   Nationality    age   Text
     ID_UK28     UK           28    Peter and Whiley have a combined age of 56
     ID_US_29    US           29    John and Aster have a combined age of 58
   ```

How do i achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully close enough, couldn't get average age:

```
import pandas as pd

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Peter', 'John', 'Wiley', 'Aster'], 'Nationality': ['UK', 'US', 'UK', 'US'], 'age': [28, 29, 28, 29]})

#make uniqueID
df['uniqueID'] = 'ID_' + df['Nationality'] + df['age'].astype(str)

#groupby has agg method that can take dict and preform multiple aggregations
df = df.groupby(['uniqueID', 'Nationality']).agg({'age': 'sum', 'Name': lambda x: ' and '.join(x)})

#to get text you just combine new Name and sum of age
df['Text'] = df['Name'] + ' have a combined age of ' + df['age'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the groupby to create the uniqueID, and you can groupby that uniqueID later to get the groups based on age and nationality.  I used a custom function to build the text str.  This one way of doing it.

```
df1 = df.assign(uniqueID='ID_'+df.Nationality+df.age.astype(str))

def myText(x):
    str = ' and '.join(x.Name)
    str += ' have a combined age of {}.'.format(x.age.sum())
    return str

df2 = df1.groupby(['uniqueID', 'Nationality','age']).apply(myText).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Text'})
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  uniqueID Nationality  age                                        Text
0  ID_UK28          UK   28  Peter and Wiley have a combined age of 56.
1  ID_US29          US   29   John and Aster have a combined age of 58.
```